# Plotting class with different marker python

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have data sets columns of features x1 and x2 and class y which has value either 0 or 1. I want to plot x1 and x2 in scatter plot such that values y == 1 will appear as "+" and values y == 0 will appear as "o".

```
x1 = np.array(100)
x2 = np.array(100)
#y = array of length 100 either with value 1 or 0
plt.scatter(x1, x2, y=1, marker='+')
plt.scatter(x1, x2, y=0, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just index your `x1` and `x2` arrays using the condition of `y==0` or `y==1`:

```
plt.scatter(x1[y==1], x2[y==1], marker='+')
plt.scatter(x1[y==0], x2[y==0], marker='o')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where` to get the indices of where the y-array is 0 or 1, and then plot them accordingly. Below is an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close('all')


x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)

arg_0 = np.where(y == 0)
arg_1 = np.where(y == 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x[arg_0], y[arg_0], marker='o')
ax.scatter(x[arg_1], y[arg_1], marker='+')
ax.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
fig.show()
```